# MenuItem.setIcon(R.id) does not work

Tags: android, android-menu

I have action bar, in which I'm dynamically swiping icon images based on few preconditions like this:

```
if(atPosition == null & parentActivity.isLocationFixed())
setActionButton(R.id.menu_plant, R.drawable.ic_menu_plant);
else
setActionButton(R.id.menu_plant, R.drawable.ic_menu_plant_disabled);
```

In setActionButton I just find appropriate item and set icon to it:

```
MenuItem item = menu.findItem(menuId);
item.setIcon(iconRes);
```

And now the weird stuff: this works for all my app except one place. I tried to logged, what goes inside, but id of that icon is correct - setIcon() just does not set that icon. I double checked icon resources, resource id also (I tried it with another icons...), but it does not set anything. Is there any cache or something which affects this behavior? I'm getting mad with that :(.

EDIT - some code:
[Pastebin 1](http://pastebin.com/1G1Wzqjp) - this works
[Pastebin 2](http://pastebin.com/iF8AgmT8) - this does not work

EDIT 2 - It's just about setIcon(). When I try to setEnabled(), it works - so I'm sure I'm calling it on right menu item.

Comment: If it is only affecting "one place," then describe that "one place" more. Is the code there different? What actions are being taken by the user when it doesn't work?

Comment: Could you post the actual code which is failing as opposed to the general idea? For example, how is `menuId` (or equivalent) calculated?

Comment: There is no difference in code between "this" and "other places". Not another thread, nothing at all. MenuId is defined in xml like the others, I'll try to pastebin some code, but there is really nothing to see :/

Comment: links to pastebin added

Answer (score -2):

Use this.It works.

```
        @Override
       public boolean onMenuItemSelected(final int featureId, final android.view.MenuItem item)
       {

           switch (item.getItemId()) {

           case R.id.icon: //menuitem id 

               Drawable iconRes = getDrawable().getResources(R.darawable.new-icon);
               item.setIcon(iconRes);
                       return false;
           }
```

Comment: thanks, but this has nothing to do with my question ;)